# jvmArgs settings for Allure reports

Tags: gradle, automated-tests, kotlin, aspectj, allure

I'm trying to generate reports by ussing

```
gradlew clean test
```

command. It fails with error:

```
Error occured during intialization of VM
Error opening zip file or JAR nanifest missing : ${configurations.agent.singleFile}
```

Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
group 'RegisteredUserFlow'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-2'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    agent
}

dependencies {
    agent 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.10'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-2'
    testCompile 'com.codeborne:selenide:4.4.3'
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.10'
    testCompile 'io.qameta.allure:allure-testng:2.0-BETA6'
    testCompile 'io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:1.6.2'
}

test.doFirst {
    jvmArgs '-javaagent:${configurations.agent.singleFile}'
}

test {
    useTestNG(){
        suites'src/test/resources/testng.xml'
    }

    systemProperty 'allure.results.directory', 'build/allure-results'
    systemProperty 'allure.link.issue.pattern', 'https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-docs/issues/{}'
    systemProperty 'allure.link.tms.pattern', 'https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-docs/issues/{}'
}
```

I've been thinking that the problems are with `aspectJ` but I'm not sure. 
Do I miss something in gradle file? Or is it somewhere in my test files? Or maybe there's a problems with latest `Allure` version? I see that `jvmArgs` is highlighted with gray (never used) - maybe problem with that?

Sorry for that much of questions I've never worked with `Allure` and `aspectJ`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this the [answer](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html) to my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you used a `String` where you should have used a `GString`.

```
jvmArgs '-javaagent:${configurations.agent.singleFile}'
```

This line is taken literally. It should have been

```
jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.agent.singleFile}"
```

to get the placeholder replaced. (single- vs. double-quotes).